# Фильтрация товаров и вывод из бд

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Подскажите как реализовать фильтр, есть форма в которой 2 категории, марка и модель,нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии на марку появлялсяя список из бд марок,далее при выборе марки подгружалась вторая категория модели исходя из  выбранной марки , после подбора марки и модели пользователь нажимает подобрать товар и его должно перебрасывать на страницу с этими товарами делал так, не получилось...

```
<form id="myForm">
                   <div class="filtr__1">
                     <div class="filtr__1__form">
                       <h1 class="filtr__1__form__title">Быстрый подбор            по авто</h1>
                        <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
                             <option id="marka-avto">марка</option>
                             <?php
                                //Выводим категории и ее ID
                                 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                               {
                               print "<option value=".$row['Id_cat'].">";
                               print $row['Name'];
                               echo("</option>");
                              }
                           ?>
                        </select>
                         <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
                            <?php
                                //Выводим категории и ее ID
                                 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                               {
                               print "<option value=".$row['Id_cat'].">";
                               print $row['Name'];
                               echo("</option>");
                              }
                           ?>
                           <option>модель</option>
                        </select>
                       <button class="filtr__1__btn">Подобрать</button>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                       $(document).ready(function(){

                       $('#idcat').change(function(){
                       $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "show.php",
                       data: "idcat="+$("#idcat").val(),
                       success: function(html){
                       $("#content").html(html);
                       }
                       });
                        return false;
                       });

                       });
                   </script>

           // БД
           <?
            $hostname = "localhost"; 
            $username = ""; 
            $password = ""; 
            $dbName = ""; 


          mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу                   создать соединение");
          mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or header('Location: Error');


           mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());
           ?>
                 // show.php
           <?php
              include "config_db.php"; //Подключаем БД
             //делаем запрос на товары этой категории
             $query = "select * from allcat where
             Id_parent=".$_REQUEST['idcat']."";
             $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
             // выводим товары полученные по запросу
             while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {
              print $row['Name']."<br>";
             }
?>
```

Comment: Советую разделить вопрос, на более маленькие и задать каждый отдельно, общество не любит читать ТЗ вместо хорошо сформулированного вопроса. Сдесь всё же помогают, а не исполняют заказы. С уважением.

Comment: jQuery Autocomplete? Мне кажется, что Вам было бы лучше реализовать небольшой сервис, который бы отвечал в JSON на запросы клиента. А за это `$query = "select * from allcat where Id_parent=".$_REQUEST['idcat']."";` нужно в угол ставить.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов это при выборе марки с помощью $.post запроса jquery забирать выборку моделей марки и дальше из них формировать список option второго селекта.